# Unable to create a snippet in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

I am trying to create a HTML 5 document snippet in Sublime Text 2. The code is shared below. I have saved the file as html5.sublime-snippet in the Sublime Text 2/Package/user directory on windows, yet when I type html5 and press tab nothing happens. I am also unable to find it when searching the snippets.
Code link https://gist.github.com/hchouhan/5352597

Answer (score 0):

ok figured it out. scope should be `<scope>text.html</scope>` and not source.html.

Comment: Just as a reference, you can use the [ScopeHunter](https://github.com/facelessuser/ScopeHunter) to view the scope under the cursor. You can also use a key command. I don't know all of them but look for "show_scope" in the default key binding file.